# Make election page responsive on localized sites

Tags: bug, design, election, localization, responsive-design

Election page on ruSO currently looks like this:

> [image]

As you can see the top part with dates and number of candidates don't fit into screen horizontally. So you can even scroll, but the rest of the page still has fixed width:

> [image]

Could you please make that page more responsive for non-English based sites?

Compare with enSO:

> [image]

Comment: Both pages behave the same way, actually. It's just that most devices are wide enough to fit the English text — only the smallest mobile devices can't. (On my small phone, I get a very small scroll bar on the English page.)

Comment: @Laurel I know. My request is to not rely on short-English-words, but make an ability to wrap long-words or make independently (of the rest of the page) scrollable title (table) with that words.